# How static fields are referenced through objects?

Tags: java, oop, static

I understand what static is but I can't find information how are the static fields referenced through the objects.

Let's imagine that we have two classes:

```
class Foo {
    static int statValue = 10;
}

class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo1 = new Foo();
        int valFromObject = foo1.statValue;

        int valFromClass = Foo.statValue;
    }
}
```

When we run this program we have one object on heap (foo1), and two classes in metaspace (simplified).

[image]

When we access static field through the class:

```
int valFromClass = Foo.statValue;
```

it is easy, because I assume that we reference class object in metaspace. But how are the static members accessed through the objects? When we write:

```
int valFromObject = foo1.statValue;
```

is the Foo instance actually involved or it is bypassed and

```
foo1.statValue;
Foo.statValue
```

are synonyms?

Comment: The static type of `foo1` (the type that was used to declare the variable, in this case `Foo`) is used to access the static field. The actual instance does not play a role.

Comment: Note that `foo1.statValue` will yield a compiler warning. You shouldn't even be writing code like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The instance is in fact not used. Java uses the type of the variable, and then reads the static (class) field.

That's why even a null with the correct type won't raise a null pointer exception.

Try this:

```
Foo foo1 = null;
int valFromObject = foo1.statValue; //will work
```

Or this:

```
int valFromNull = ((Foo)null).statValue; //same thing
```

Accessing static class members through instances is discouraged for obvious reasons (the most important being the illusion that an instance member is being referenced, in my opinion). Java lets use `foo1.statValue`, with a warning (`"The static field Foo.statValue should be accessed in a static way"` as reported by my IDE).

Comment: I'm still wondering why they allowed `foo1.statValue;` in the first place.